# Why is READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT not on by default?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, isolation-level, read-committed-snapshot

Simple question?

**Why is `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` not on by default?**

I'm guessing either backwards compatibility, performance, or both?

**[Edit]** Note that I'm interested in the effect relating to the READ_COMMITTED isolation level, and not the snapshot isolation level.

Why would this be a breaking-change, as it holds less locks, and still doesn't read non-committed rows?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both. Mostly compatibility.

Turning snapshot on by default would break the vast majority of applications that expect the old, blocking, behavior. Snapshot makes **heavy** use of tempdb for the version store and its impact on performance is quite measurable.

Comment: Could you elaborate how this can break an application that "relies on blocking behavior"? I have done much research and cannot fathom how anyone could come to this conclusion.

Answer (score 20):

> Turning snapshot on by default would break the vast majority of applications

It is unclear to me if it will break the "vast majority" of applications. Or, if it will break many applications in ways that are hard to identify and/or hard to work around. The SQL Server documentation states that `READ COMMITTED` and `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` both satisfy the ANSI definition of `READ COMMITTED`. (Stated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122.aspx) So, as long as your code does not rely on anything beyond the literal ANSI-required behavior, in theory, you will be okay.

A complication is that the ANSI specification doesn't capture everything that people commonly think things like dirty read, fuzzy/non-repeatable read, etc. mean in practice. And, there are anomalies (permitted by the ANSI definitions) that can occur under `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` that cannot occur under `READ COMMITTED`. For an example, see http://www.jimmcleod.net/blog/index.php/2009/08/27/the-potential-dangers-of-the-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-level/.

Also see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/d1b3d46e-2642-4bc7-a68a-0e4b8da1ca1b.

For deep information on the differences between the isolation levels, start with http://www.cs.umb.edu/cs734/CritiqueANSI_Iso.pdf (`READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` was not around when this paper was written, but the other levels are covered by it).

Comment: Actually, (Perhaps it has changed), the answer is this : _Turning snapshot on by default would break the vast majority of applications **that expect the old, blocking, behavior**_. My understanding is that there are existing applications relying on this pessimistic locking strategy, expected to be paused waiting for lock acquiring.

Answer (score 4):

It changes the default locking strategy from how the Sybase/SQL Server family have worked forever. It'd break all my applications, all the application I know of at my shop, and corrupt a lot of important data.

Read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_isolation) *completely*: do you want the code behind your banking app to use this isolation model?

> In general, therefore, snapshot
>   isolation puts some of the problem of
>   maintaining non-trivial constraints
>   onto the user, who may not appreciate
>   either the potential pitfalls or the
>   possible solutions. The upside to this
>   transfer is better performance.

It's a compromise like most database designs. In my case, I can deal with the locking waits/deadlocks (rare) as a price for easier and more "out of the box" data integrity. I've yet to come across a problem or issue where I see snapshot isolation as a solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate how READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT could lead to corrupted data?

Comment: This answer is referring to SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION which is different from READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT